# Removing date from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting some content into a website and need to process the entry titles so that they don't contain any dates. More specifically, a string such as "Lorem ipsum 30-08-2011 dolor" needs to become "Lorem ipsum dolor". I have to take into account dates such as: 30-08-2011, 30.08.2011 and 30/08/2011.

After searching around I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
str.replace(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.]\d{4}$/, '');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `^` and `$` if you want to match the pattern inside a string. Your current regex will only match a string that *only* contains a date.

Also, if you want to remove multiple dates from a string, you need to use a global regex, by adding a `g` after the closing `/`.

```
str.replace(/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.]\d{4}/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace(/\d{1,2}[\-|\.|\/]\d{1,2}[\-|\.|\/]\d{2,4}/g, "")`

http://jsfiddle.net/cJCBE/

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkDate(date) {
  var re = /^\d{2}[.\/-]\d{2}[.\/-]\d{4}$/;
  return re.test(date);
}
```